# Can I run windows phone 8 on windows 8 RT and vice versa?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

Can I run RT apps on windows phone, or windows 8 phone apps on windows 8 RT or PRO?

If I need to develop an app to run on RT tablets and on windows 8 phones, what should I do?

**EDIT**

When Microsoft will provide a unified way to develop apps????

Am I requested to develop tons of apps to run on all of Microsoft platforms, I am not an Apple fan at all, but Microsoft should learn more and more from them, I spent and am spending all of my time chasing Microsoft techniques, it is very very annoying!!! :(

Comment: That will be in Windows CE ME NT XP RT 11.x.A Series III.  Circa 2030. Check back then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No,

But you can share code through the use of Portable Class Libraries or linked files.

I recently wrote two articles about how to achieve this:

The first one is about whether to choose PCL's or linked files:
http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/03/27/portable-class-libraries-or-source-code-sharing/

The second one is about how to work around the limitations of PCL's:
http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/02/24/patterns-for-sharing-code-in-windows-phone-and-windows-8-applications/

Comment: Cool.  Because .net  assemblies were so last decade, it is time to learn a new microsoft library and linking system. :-)

Comment: Actually the linking system is there since .NET 1.1 (more correct VS 2003, since it's an IDE feature) and has been used well before that in other technologies. The PCL's are new and I think in future versions we'll see the API's grow more towards each other

Answer (score 4):

No.  The two runtimes are not compatible.

> If I need to develop an app to run on RT tablets and on windows 8 phones, what should I do?

You can use [the portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) to save *logic*, but not the presentation code.

You would then build your UI on each platform, using the appropriate tools for the platform.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just run a xap on a tablet. You CAN however take almost all of the XAML and C# uncompiled code and recompile for the tablet. You just need to fix some of the idiosyncrasies in the syntax. Same goes for Windows 8 Pro.